# How to update svn version base number after applying a patch

Tags: eclipse, svn

Is there any way that I can "update" svn base number after applying a patch?

For example right now my project has base revision: 860 and I want to add manually patches till revision 864 ( Head is 866). After applying those patches is there any way that I can update base revision number in order to be visible inside eclipse?

[image]

Comment: If you don't have any uncommitted changes, right-click the project and choose _Replace With > Revision or URL..._ (Subversive). Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: @howlger Thanks for the reply but i don't mean this. As you mentioned i have on the project uncommitted changes and that's why I want to add those patches manually. But, also I need to be able to "set" or update the svn BASE revision to the latest patch applied.

Comment: Did you right-click + _Team > Apply patch_ or what do you mean by _add manually patches_? These patches have already committed to the server, right? By _Replace With > Revision or URL..._ your local BASE will replaced by the selected revision, but also your working copy.

Comment: Yes that's how i insert the patches right-click +Team > Apply Patch. My concern is if i do Replace With as you mentioned it will update my working copy. does that mean that i will lose my changes?

Comment: Yes, _Replace With_ overwrites both, Base and Working Copy. But if I understood you correctly, your Local Copy is already equal to revision 864 (this can be checked with _Compare With > Revision or URL..._). What I don't understand is why you manually apply patches.

Comment: I need add the patches manually because i have to review most of them. Even if they are committed.But i also need to be able to track on which "new BASE" revision i am. If it not possible for example to write something like svn setBASE 864 its ok, i guess i will use the old way write the new base on a paper.

Comment: I see. Then how about to get the latest from the repository and apply the reverse patch (in the _Apply Patch_ dialog, on the second page check the _Reverse patch_ checkbox): only the Base would contain the changes in contrast to the Working Copy, and comparing and reverting the changes to review would be easy?